# I got null value in JsonArray webapi c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I got below response

```
{
    "json_array": 
    [
        {
            "param1": null,
            "param2": null,
            "param3": null,
            "param4": null
        },
        {
            "param1": null,
            "param2": null,
            "param3": null,
            "param4": null
        }
   ],
   "status": "true"
}
```

> I want this type of response if all value is null in class.

```
{
    "json_array": [],
    "status": "true"
}
```

**AND** I pass this type of response if not null

```
{
"json_array": 
[
    {
        "param1": "123",
        "param2": "true",
        "param3": "success",
        "param4": "1"
    },
    {
        "param1": "129",
        "param2": "true",
        "param3": "success",
        "param4": "2"
    }
 ],
 "status": "true" }
```

**I returning object of class and I pass like this in for loop**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MethodCheckin(RequestClass CR)
    {
        RequestClass[] ICOARPOST = CR.postobject;

        MyClass[] responcearrayPost = new MyClass[ICOARPOST.Length];

        Response_Class _CR = new Response_Class();

        if (ICOARPOST == null || ICOARPOST.Length == 0)
        {
            _CR.status = Constant.False;
            _CR.datapost = responcearrayPost;
            return Ok(_CR);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ICOARPOST.Length; i++)
        {
            MyClass s = await _Services.Method(ICOARPOST[i].param1, ICOARPOST[i].param2);

            responcearrayPost[i] = s;
        }

        _CR.status = Constant.True;
        _CR.datapost = responcearrayPost;

        return Ok(_CR);
    }
```

Here is my Class,

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string param1 { get; set; }

        public string param2 { get; set; }

        public string param3 { get; set; }

        public string param4 { get; set; }
    }
```

here is function in which i return value in class,

```
public async Task<MyClass> AsyncDay(string param1, string param2)
{
    MyClass _myclass = new MyClass();


    if (Time >= 86400000 && Time < 172800000)
    {
        if (day == 1)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            _myclass.param1 = "123";
            _myclass.param2 = "1";
            _myclass.param3 = "success";
            _myclass.param4 = "true";
        }
    }
    else if (Time >= 172800000 && Time < 259200000)
    {
        if (day == 2)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            _myclass.param1 = "123";
            _myclass.param2 = "1";
            _myclass.param3 = "success";
            _myclass.param4 = "true";
        }
    }
        return _myclass;        
}
```

Comment: Cab you edit your question to show an example of what _"all value is null in class"_ is, and how you're creating the json?

Comment: @stuartd I added more code please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this code in ConsoleApplication, but it should work. If you have an instance of the object, you can easy check it like this:

```
        public class JsonArray
        {
            public string param1 { get; set; }
            public string param2 { get; set; }
            public string param3 { get; set; }
            public string param4 { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            public List<JsonArray> json_array { get; set; }
            public bool status { get; set; }
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            // init
            var myClassObj = new MyClass();

            myClassObj.json_array = new List<JsonArray>();
            myClassObj.json_array.Add(new JsonArray { param1 = null, param2 = null, param3 = null, param4 = null });
            myClassObj.json_array.Add(new JsonArray { param1 = null, param2 = null, param3 = null, param4 = null });
            myClassObj.status = true;

            // to JSON
            var json = FilterAndGetJsonFromObject(myClassObj);
        }

        public static string FilterAndGetJsonFromObject(MyClass myClassObj)
        {
            // filter null params
            foreach (var jsonArray in myClassObj.json_array.ToList())
            {
                if (jsonArray.param1 == null && jsonArray.param2 == null && jsonArray.param3 == null && jsonArray.param4 == null)
                {
                    myClassObj.json_array.Remove(jsonArray);
                }
            }

            // serialize to json
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myClassObj);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use `List<T>`?

```
var resultList = List<MyClass>();

for (int i = 0; i < ICOARPOST.Length; i++)
{
    MyClass s = await _Services.Method(ICOARPOST[i].param1, ICOARPOST[i].param2);

    if(s != null)
    {
        resultList.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is something like this :

```
    List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ICOARPOST.Length; i++)
    {
        MyClass s = await _Services.Method(ICOARPOST[i].param1, ICOARPOST[i].param2);

        //no idea if this is how it works. might as well be s.Value != null or something similar
        if(s != null)
            items.add(s);
    }

    responcearrayPost = items.ToArray();
```

but to be honest, your example is far from complete, so i can't tell if this does you any good.

Comment: class parameters are null when i return class

Answer (score -1):

You are using loop to execute method and it get sMyClass s which class object in response. 
you check the value if null or empty then restrict to assign in object 
responcearrayPost[i] = s;

```
if(s !=null)
responcearrayPost[i] = s;
```

Comment: Take another good look at your code. this way you would still end up with null values in your array despite the null check.